# Black canvas instead of image

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a problem with canvas. Let's say, 1/10 time I have black square instead of my image, on chrome. My code is as follow, how can I modify it in order to avoid this black display?

```
<canvas id="Canvas" width="954" height="267"></canvas>

<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Map sprite
var mapSprite = new Image();
mapSprite.src = 'image.png';

var main = function () {
    draw();
};

var draw = function () {
    // Clear Canvas
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Draw diagramme
    context.drawImage(mapSprite, 0, 0, 954, 267);
}

main();
</script>
```

EDIT 1: full function draw :

```
 var draw = function () {
    // Clear Canvas
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Draw diagramme
    context.drawImage(mapSprite, 0, 0, nextWidth, nextHeight);

    //draw all precedent cross
    cross = new Image();
    cross.src = "cross.png";

    for (var i = 0; i < array_x.length; i++) {
    context.drawImage(cross, array_x[i], array_y[i], 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: wait for the image to load? Do `mainSprite.onload = main` instead of `main()`, at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to wait until image is loaded.

Replace:

```
main();
```

With:

```
mapSprite.addEventListener('load', main);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. That seems to solve the image problem. In reality, my function is a little bit more complicated (EDIT 1). I have 2 arrays containing coordinate and want to plot them on the image. With your solution, I have my image, but now, i do not have my coordinate (cross).